# GWT message box with closable icon

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using gxt(2.6) messagebox in my gwt application..
  I tried this following code to keep closable icon..but its not working

Messagebox.setclosable(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a unfixed bug in gxt 2.6 ..I reviewed the alert() function in MessageBox.class..

```
public static Messagebox alert(String title, String msg,
        Listener<MessageboxEvent> callback) {
    Messagebox box = new Messagebox();
    box.setTitle(title);
    box.setMessage(msg);
    box.callback = callback;
    box.setButtons(OK);
    box.icon = WARNING;
    box.show();

    return box;
}
```

If we add **box.setClosable(true);** this in existing method it will work fine

public static Messagebox alert(String title, String msg,
            Listener callback) {
        Messagebox box = new Messagebox();
        box.setTitle(title);
        box.setMessage(msg);
        box.callback = callback;
        box.setButtons(OK);
        box.icon = WARNING;
        box.setClosable(true);
        box.show();

```
    return box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bug?:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?50995-FIXED-Bug-in-MessageBox.setClosable%28true%29

You could also easily build a custom component to have a popup window with "close" button, such as:

```
public class EnhancedDialogBox extends DialogBox {

    public EnhancedDialogBox(String header, String text){
        setText(header);
        FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
        Button ok = new Button("Close");
        ok.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                EnhancedDialogBox.this.hide();
            }
        });
        Label lbl = new Label(text);
        fp.add(lbl);
        fp.add(ok);
        add(fp);
    }

}
```

in case of dire need or as a quick and dirty fix or workaround.

Comment: Hi Abdul, where you able to check if this is a bug or a fix / workaround for it? Thanks.